# Can't connect to MongoDb 4.0.9 on Windows server with shell

Tags: mongodb

I have MongoDb 4.0.9 running as a service on Windows Server 2016 Standard.

This is my mongod.cfg:

[image: List item]

- For testing purposes I turned off the server's firewall completely.
- I am not using SSH or any other tunnel so far
- The Windows service logs on as "Network Service"
- I have one user in the "admin" database with roles "userAdminAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase" and "readWriteAnyDatabase"

My local machine is Windows 10 and here I have Mongo 4.0.9 installed as well.  I am trying to connect to my server's database by shell:

[image]

When I go on the server (Remote Desktop) I can connect successfully (same user credentials):

[image]

I am running out of ideas what I am doing wrong when remote connecting.

What is also confusing: I am doing the exact same thing on another server (different provider, different database, but also Windows Server 2016 Standard, MongoDb 4.0.9 and the same user and roles). And here I **CAN** connect.

So, I assume it has something to do with the settings of Windows Server (and not Mongo ...)?

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: it sounds like your servers may have whitelist IP addresses that are allowed to connect on port 27017? Your remote desktop connects to localhost.

Comment: Hello pandaab. Whitelist IPs? I don't think so. Besides: the firewall is completely turned off currently. And yes, when I run RDP, I am connecting to localhost (because I am on the machine). What is you suggestion?

Comment: Hi Ingmar, have you tried connect to server from any linux/ ubuntu machine. Please check once if you have any. So that we can understand where issue exactly lies.

Comment: Hello Priyanka, unfortunately I don't have a Linux machine. Do you really think it makes a difference?

Comment: If you can able to connect mongodb on remonte sever then there is huge chance that you have not opened the default `27017` port on the remonte server. Which is restricting you to being connected with your local machine/mongoshell/robomongo/compass. Just go to the web service which you are using and open that port.

Comment: @Fanpark: My firewall is completely turned off (see the first bullet in my post). Thank you though ...

Comment: @Fanpark: Thank you again. But I am sorry. You are suggesting, I should open port 27017, but you are not talking about the firewall? I might not be seeing the woods before the trees, but I am not sure what you are talking about. ".. go to the web service... ". You mean the web service that "MongoDb Server" is running, right?

Comment: @Fanpark: Oh, sorry. I was too fast. I thought you meant "Windows Service". Mongo is running as a Windows Service on my server (on which the firewall is completely disabled for now). But you wrote *Web* Service? I didn't know there is a web service involved when I want to access MongoDB by mongo shell. Totally lost now. Sorry ;)

Comment: How do you connect to your server? Probably using SSH?

Comment: @Fanpark: No. No SSL/SSH/VPN or whatever. For now I am just using mongo.exe without any tricks (or security features). It's working perfectly on one of my servers, but not on the other. And I have no idea what is different about both machines other than that they are hosted at different providers. They are both designated severs (Windows Server 2016 Standard).

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather, it seems your the Windows Machine running the MongoDB service is hosted in the cloud.

If you are certain the windows firewall is turned off (make sure to disable it on Private, Public and Domain - if applicable)

Furthermore, my best guess is that the port might be block by the cloud hosting provider firewall.

Usually they provide the basic port openings (21, 80, 443, 1433, 3389, etc) - and port which are not common for windows (like 27017) are blocked (filtered) by default.

if you wish to verify this, run the following:
`nmap <server hostname>` to get the default ports checked.
for MongoDB run `nmap -p 27017 <server hostname>`

Comment: Hi Shadar, thank you so much. I believe we are getting somewhere. I installed Nmap on both my server and my local machine. Nmap's response on my server: "27017/tcp open mongod". However, when I run Nmap from my local machine: "27017/tcp filtered mongod". So, it might really be some additional firewall on my provider's side. And it would explain why all this works on my other server (different provider). But: both servers are designated (not shared and no cloud).

Comment: just to clarify - I understood clearly it's not a shared instance (as you run your own Windows Server 2016 instance ... why windows BTW and not linux?). further more, if it was a shared instance 27017 would have been open ...
Talk to you hosting provider, or look at their FAQ - i'm pretty sure they'll have a section on opening ports.

Comment: I was on the phone for 2h with my server provider today. They were able to reproduce my problems and couldn't find the reason so far. They will forward the problem to their own firewall team. I will come back to you guys, as soon as I have news. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe simply switch providers? Get an EC2 instance on amazon ...?